# window.document.write - write html element and more

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have opened a new window, and now I have a button in this new window.  Under this button there is a JavaScript function which should submit the form and insert some content into a `<p>`.  This "to-add" content also has a html element (close button).

This inserting job is not working.  Here is what I tried:

```
myWindow.document.write("<scrip" + "t>function closeme(){ document.getElementById('danke').innerHTML='thanks <input type=\'button\' onclick=\'window.close()\'/>'; } </sc" + "ript>");
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: First of all, don't use `document.write` - create a script element via `createElement` instead. This will alleviate your quotes inside of quotes inside of quotes nightmare. Second of all, nothing ever calls your `closeme` function?

Comment: @jbabey, no, my function ``closeme`` is being called, i just didnot post it here, because i am sure it is being called. but generally, ``createElement`` is better way? - :))) you made me laugh!

Comment: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments there are better ways to insert scripts, but in the interests of answering the question, you have to escape the escape characters as well so that they will be present in the output.

```
myWindow.document.write("<scrip" + "t>function closeme(){ " + 
"document.getElementById('danke').innerHTML='thanks <input type=\\\'button\\\' " + 
"onclick=\\\'window.close()\\\'/>'; } </sc" + "ript>");
```

(line breaks added for readability)

Comment: how can i link jquery to document? 
``myWindow.document.write("<head>");``
``myWindow.document.write("jquery link")``
``myWindow.document.write("</head>")``   is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

I agree there are better ways of doing this, but regarding your specific question. There are escaping issues:

```
myWindow.document.write("<scrip" + "t>function closeme(){ document.getElementById('danke').innerHTML='thanks <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.close()\" />'; } </sc" + "ript>");
```

I'd honestly add `text/javascript` for consistency.